# mongoose document lock that document not read by another when transaction commit

Tags: mysql, node.js, laravel, mongoose

i am trying to implement send vouchers to customers for multiple logins and send vouchers if two users login at a time and send vouchers the two users access same voucherid how to implement one user read  vouchers not access to the another users.

const mongoose =require("mongoose")

```
    const {Transaction-manager}= require("mongodb-tx")  

    const mgr = new Transaction-manager({mongoose})  

    await mgr.transaction(async (t) => {  

    let voucher_Ids = await vouchers.find({ voucher_status: 'Created', status: true }, { _id: 1 },{transaction: t, lock: t.LOCK}).limit(issue.vouchers_count);

                console.log(voucher_Ids)

                if (!voucher_Ids) {

                    throw new Error("conditions not satisfied")

                }

                })
```